# Running app using push notification in iOS

Tags: ios

Can the iOS push notifications be used to automatically execute the attached application somehow (without user action)?

Comment: Kindly describe more, what purpose you want app, what to advice etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually no, when your app is in terminated (killed) state and you receive push notification, then app doesn't get wake up in back ground and your any piece of code will not get executed.

If your app is VOIP based or in particular App Store category ( permission had to be taken in advance from Apple development ) then you can you push kit ( silent notification ).

Using local notification based on your push kit payload. Unless sound file plays. Your app will get wake up background and you can execute your piece of code( max for 30 seconds) till sound file plays.

Comment: Nice remark about the force-quit state, thank you for adding this!